# Rails 3 + Declarative Authorization: nested permissions

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, declarative-authorization

I'm using declarative authorization. Let's say I have two models/controllers named `batch` and `timetable_entry`. I want the users with permission to access `/batches/:batch_id (batches#show)` to be able to access `/batches/:batch_id/timetable_entries (timetable_entries#index)`.

So far, I've come up with this:

```
has_permission_on :batches do
  to :show
    if_attribute :some_condition do
      has_permission_on :timetable_entries do
        to :index
      end
    end
  end
end
```

This doesn't achieve what I want, as the user is unable to access `timetable_entries#index`.  What can I do? Thanks!